# Auto folding of JSX React components in - Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

I am looking for an Atom package that handles **automatic** 'folding / collapsing' of functions.

I have been using a package called 'fold-functions', however it does not seem to play well with arrow functions or JSX code.

*Does anyone know of an auto-folding package that works with ReactJS Apps written in ES6?*

Comment: https://orktes.github.io/atom-react/#code-folding something like this?

Comment: I believe OP is looking for something which does this automatically.

Comment: Yes sorry I did state 'auto', imo its just easier to traverse code with all blocks folded on opening.